# align horizontally divs in 2 different columns

Tags: html, css, layout

I've set up my site with a basic layout of 2 columns header and footer. On most of my pages this works as the left column isn't connected to the right. However on one page I've got a picture in the left column with an associated description in the right. Both of these elements will vary in height, but not width. Now, I got it to work by placing a div between the pictures clear-all with a set height to compensate for the difference on the right side. Looks good in the browser that I tested it with but when I did a final look using ie, chrome, opera, and firefox I found that each one is rendering the space differently. The height of the left column is not consistent so that the pictures don't line up with the description on the right. I would like to keep the 2 column layout consistent thru out my site. I there a way to compensate different browser renderings in this type of layout? [Here's](http://www.craig-smith.comlu.com) a link to the page, I launched it because I don't really expect much traffic yet. Thanks for any suggestions!

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers render things differently (like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on). To get everything to a common value you are supposed to use a `reset.css`. The most popular and what I am generally using in my projects is this one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ . From what I can see on your website you are not using a `reset.css`. You need to grab a copy of that file (from the attached link), name it reset.css and import it before your actual `style.css` file -- in your case you have to import it before this rule: `@import url("site_css/craig-smith.css");`

**NOTE:** After importing the reset, you might have to adjust some of the original `craig-smith.css`, but in the end the rendering will look similar/consistent in all browsers.